# How do I set up a shared folder between Kali and Windows (Given my restrictions)?

Tags: networking, windows, kali, file-sharing

I'm currently trying to get a shared folder set up between my Pi3 running the 32bit version of Kali, and my windows machine.

I am trying to do this across a corporate network which is throwing some spanners in the works. 
Both devices are on the company network, and I can SSH into the Pi, and also view the desktop with a VNC viewer.

I am struggling as most of the guides I am finding either relate to kali being run in a  VM (not relevant), Require a shared folder to be created on the windows side (This cannot be done in this corporate environment due to security risks), or through samba requiring changing the workgroup of the machine (cannot be done as it has to remain in the corporate domain with this config).

How else can I produce a shared folder?

Comment: SSHfs has terrible perfromance but may be what you need

Comment: The question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. It is about general setup a Samba server that can be done on every Linux like operating system. You better ask at https://superuser.com/